# Fresh install won't boot throwing "error: end of disk"

Tags: installation, grub2

I have a [machine](http://www.giada.cc/chanpinzhongxin/minipc/cube%20series/2009-11-04/3.html) which is supposed to be a media server. I have tried to install Ubuntu (both alternate and regular i386). The installation (and boot to usb drive) went on fine, but after the install I tried to load the machine and it froze.

In the case of i386 I get the error "**hd0 out of disk**" and am left with a grub rescue console. `set` gives:

> prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub
>   root=hd0,msdos1

[Following ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Rescue%20Mode%20%28%27%27grub%20rescue%3E%27%27%29%20Booting), I replaced msdos1 with 1 which didn't work.

In the case of the alternate install, I only get a blinking cursor on the top left (I waited for about two minutes).

If I wait a really long time in the alternate version, I get:

```
error: no such partition  
grub rescue>
```

Nothing works in this mode as well. I also tried to replace `(hd0,1)` with `(hd0,sda)` or `(hd0,0)` but this doesn't seam to have an effect.

Install information:

1. Single hard drive
2. Install on a hard drive via usb thumb drive
3. Ubuntu's default hard drive portioning and formatting (use entire hard drive)
4. Ubuntu Natty

How can I fix this?

Comment: ubuntu natty. I'm using usb thumb drive to install to hard disk. I have let ubuntu yo choose it's default partitioning (use and erase entire hard drive)

Comment: Have you tried the recover options when running the install again from the thumb drive. I might also try re installing grub. If you can boot into a live environment.

Comment: Yes, I tried the recover operation after the new install. I don't think that re installing grub will work since this will be the exact same operation as the one carried by the install process. I'll try though...

Comment: Is this a standard sata hard drive or a ssd hard drive.

Comment: @nelaar, This is an interesting question. I don't think this is a ssd since this is a cheap machine. The manufacture claims this is a SATA2 hard drive. I'm not sure since I remember this is a 320GB Toshiba hard drive with S.M.A.R.T technoligy while the link I posted state this is a 250 GB. When I'll get back home I'll check this.

Comment: from the live boot off the usb stick enter recover console and type fdisk -l; please paste the fdisk -l out put here. If you can also paste the /etc/fstab file of the installed system that would also help

Comment: @Yotam let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/990/discussion-between-nelaar-and-yotam)

Comment: @Yotam - did you find a solution in chat? Can you post it as an answer here if you did please?

Comment: @DannyStaple: No I didn't turns out that the hard drive was flawed

Answer (score 2):

I would start with testing your hardware. It is probably not RAM but I would test that first anyway to prove it isn't a problem.

Next I would move onto the hard drive. You could try the diagnostics on the Ultimate Boot CD. There is a tool for most brands of hard drive. The other thing I would recommend is to try a different hard drive in your machine. Also changing USB cables if this is a desktop machine.

Hopefully at some point during this process you isolated the problem. If not then I think it is probably a software issue not hardware.