# GRUB rescue error: hd0 out of disk

Tags: grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fresh install won't boot, error: end of disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55700/fresh-install-wont-boot-error-end-of-disk)

I was playing a game on my multiboot Windows 7 + Ubuntu laptop. It froze, so I force shutdown the computer. When I load it back up, I get:

```
error: hd0 out of disk.
```

When I do `ls`, it gives me:

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos6) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)
```

But when I try to do `insmod (hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub/linux.mod`, I get:

```
error: hd0 out of disk
```

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance.