# error : hd0 out of disk grub rescue

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fresh install won't boot, error: end of disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55700/fresh-install-wont-boot-error-end-of-disk)

My laptop Asus eee pc 1001 PX fell down and cannot boot anymore. I was on ubuntu 12.04. Here is what happen on start up
1/ a slight noise for the hard drive
2/ Then the screen display the following

error :hd0 out of disk.
grub rescue>

By typing ls:
(hd0) (hd0,msdos6) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos1)

By typing set:
prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub
root=hd0,msdos1

I cannot access further in the files with say ls (hd0,msdos6)... answering unknown filesystem

Neither can I boot from a live version of Ubuntu with a USB stick saying there is no bootable device even by disabling all other disks but the USB stick.

And sudo command is unknown.

I am afraid HD may be broken but in case there is any clues, helps or solutions to boot or at least save datas you're welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Neither can I boot from a live version of Ubuntu with a USB stick saying there is no bootable device even by disabling all other disks but the USB stick.

This is a serious problem as not only your hard drive might be damaged, but also your motherboard. Disabling all drives but the USB should definitely get you to boot on the live USB if nothing else. If Ubuntu then did not find the hard drive, it could be broken, but as of right now there might be something seriously wrong with your motherboard because it wont even boot from USB.

Try another USB port and another USB drive for good measure, and make sure you're really asking the computer manually boot from the USB drive (usually called "boot device selection" on one of the F-buttons on boot). If this does not work, your computer is likely broken. Look into repairing it or buying a new one.